# How to force dde23 function to generate output after fixed time step

Tags: matlab, ode, timedelay

I am solving a delay differential equation using MATLAB dde23 function. I want to use the output generated by the first dde23 function in the second dde23 function. Here is the code

```
tspan=[0:1:1440]';
x0=1.7;

%1st function 
% options = ddeset('OutputFcn',@odeplot,'OutputSel',1);
sol = dde23(@dd,70,x0,tspan,options);
y_obs=sol.y; 
tspan_new=sol.x;

%{2nd function 
x1=[x0 ; 0.1; 0.01; 0.01];
final_sol = dde23(@ddc,70,x1,tspan,[],y_obs);
y_fit=final_sol.y;
tdata=final_sol.x;
%}
```

The time series I generated as an input to the first function is of size 1441 but the size of tspan_new and y_obs is 212 (generated from the dde23 output). I am unable to understand why the size is changing. 
Is it possible to output y_obs at each time point provided in the input i.e. is it possible to obtain y_obs of length 1441 in this case ? 
Since the size of output is different I am unable to use y_obs vector in my second function. The size of y_fit and tdata is again entirely different from y_obs and tspan.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the [ODE Suite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html#bu3n5rf-1) that implements a [dense output routine](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7362/intermediate-values-interpolation-after-runge-kutta-calculation) as part of its time march, [`dde23`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dde23.html) requires an explicit post-[`deval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) to accomplish what you're after:

```
tspan=[0:1:1440]';
x0=1.7;

%1st function 
sol   = dde23(@dd,70,x0,tspan([1,end]),options);
y_obs = deval(sol,tspan);
```

This function uses local Hermite cubic interpolation on the mesh generated by its dynamic time-stepping routine to approximate the `y` value at the requested `t` values.

Comment: Is there some way to set the time points at which the y_obs will be outputted before the dde23 call ? I am using y_obs generated from function 1 in the function 2. Since the 2nd function is evaluating at different set of time points. I get an error saying there is a dimension mismatch.

Comment: @NikhilPillai As far as I know, there is no way to, and probably wouldn't want to, disable the dynamic time-stepping that is critical to these DE algorithms.  I think you need to ask another question that fully addresses your need with runnable code.